# Analyze EF Core query cache

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In our .NET 7 application, we see the EF Core Event Counter [`compiled-query-cache-hit-rate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/event-counters?tabs=windows#counters-and-their-meaning) always far below 100%. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant#query-caching-and-parameterization), this shouldn't be the case:

> If this counter remains stable below 100%, that is an indication that your application may be doing something which defeats the query cache - it's a good idea to investigate that.

I'd like to know how to investigate that. Can I somehow elicit from EF Core which query cannot be cached and needs to be recompiled?

Since we're using PostgreSQL with [Array Type Mapping](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html) and this feature doesn't seem to get used frequently, the following query made me wonder if it might cause the issue:

```cs
public class Service
{
    internal static readonly List<ProcessState> NoReevaluationIsNeededStates = new() { ProcessState.Received };

    public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(string referencedKey)
    {
        await using MyDbContext context = await ContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
        return await context.Points
            .Where(point => point.Keys.Contains(referencedKey) && !NoReevaluationIsNeededStates.Contains(point.State))
            .ExecuteUpdateAsync(entity => entity.SetProperty(point => point.State, ProcessState.Processed));
    }
}

public class Point
{
    public List<string> Keys { get; set; }

    public ProcessState State { get; set; }
}

public enum ProcessState
{
    Received,
    Processed
}
```

Please note that there are several other EF Core queries in our code that I didn't share here - the previous snippet was just the most complex I could find.

Comment: Just checked EF Core code, this query should have cache hit 100%. Or there is bug in generating cache key.

Comment: Okay, then maybe it's another query. Do you know how to analyze the EF Core query cache?

Comment: `options.ReplaceService<ICompiledQueryCache, MyCompiledQueryCache>()`. Sample implementation is in [CompiledQueryCache](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/release%2F7.0/src/EFCore/Query/Internal/CompiledQueryCache.cs) - you can [see](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/release%2F7.0/src/EFCore/Query/Internal/CompiledQueryCache.cs#L64) when cache miss is set.

Comment: Try to enable the logging of the `CoreEventId.QueryCompilationStarting` event:  `options.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Log(CoreEventId.QueryCompilationStarting))`

Comment: Using `options.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Log(CoreEventId.QueryCompilationStarting))` does not log anything  I'll give `MyCompiledQueryCache` a try

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv how get I retrieve a logger for `MyCompiledQueryCache`? I tried the general .NET approach of requesting an `ILogger<T>` from the DI container which fails with `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.ILogger<MyCompiledQueryCache>'`

Comment: It is Core service, probably you have no access to DI here. `MyCompiledQueryCache` will be created only once per `DbContextOptions`. So usually once per application.

Comment: `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query": "Information"` was missing in `appsettings.json`, now I can see the `CoreEventId.QueryCompilationStarting` logs

Comment: It would be good to build cache query misses into a P.R gate.

Comment: What do you mean by _P.R gate_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a little blog post about it ([see here](https://mu88.github.io/2023/03/13/EF-Core-query-cache.html)), but long story short: our Grafana dashboard contains these metric values:
[image]

All the `-1` values are obviously bringing down the average ‍♂️ and `-1` is returned if the cache hasn't been used ([EF Core sources on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/EntityFrameworkEventSource.cs#L226)), e. g. if there is no traffic and therefore no DB queries.

Big thanks to [@svyatoslav-danyliv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10646316/svyatoslav-danyliv) and [@Alberto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1018140/alberto) for your input!